# Mecrisp Forth is not responding on TI LaunchPad MSP-EXP430G2ET (MSP430G2553)

Tags: forth

I uploaded the Mecrisp Forth hex file for MSP430G2553 successfully using the TI UniFlash cloud tool.

(I've used the same tool to flash other Mecrisp Forth hex files for MSP430F5529 and TI Tiva LaunchPad, as well.)

Unfortunately, there is no response from the Tera Term, running at a 9600 baud rate.

(I've used the same [Tera Term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tera_Term) to talk to Mecrisp Forth running on MSP430F5529 and Tiva successfully.)

I paid attention to the hardware RX/TX business of the earlier G2 LaunchPad. In fact, the latest EXP430G2ET has it marked clearly on the board, and it comes with the crystal soldered.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

The flash memory must be ***completely erased*** first (setting all bytes to 0xFF). It is *not* enough to just flash the Mecrisp Forth software.

(It is in the documentation, and I have positively observed it to be crucial installing Mecrisp Forth on an ARM-based microcontroller board, [1Bitsy](https://github.com/1bitsy/1bitsy-hardware), which has an ARM Cortex-M4F microcontroller, [STM32F415RGT6](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/98/9f/89/73/01/b1/48/98/DM00035129.pdf/files/DM00035129.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00035129.pdf) (it had other problems with a non-standard baud-rate, but that is another story). I had [previously installed some other software on the 1Bitsy](http://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2017/06/getting-started-with-1bitsy-and-black.html) and that was enough for Mecrisp Forth to not work.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possibilities, and you can try to eliminate a few of them with simple tests. For example, check the communication chain:

1. test the PC (Tera Term) part by connecting TxD to RxD and see if there is an echo.
2. test the MCU part - after reset, there is a relatively long message on the TxD - you can see it with a LED.